# private method 'split' called for (Shoes::EditLine):Shoes::EditLine

Tags: ruby, shoes

I am trying to write a simple program that takes a rgb value and changes the background to that color using Shoes (Raisins revision 1134). Here is my code:

```
Shoes.app :title => "Show a Color" do

    def convert_to_num(value)
    # Splits string into numerical values
        value.split(',').map { |num| num.to_i }
    end 

    def to_rgb(value)
        red, green, blue = convert_to_num(value)
        rgb(red, green, blue)
    end  

    stack :height => 500, :width => 500 do
        value = edit_line
        button "Change color!" do
            background to_rgb(value)
        end
    end

end
```

When I run it, I get this error: private method 'split' called for (Shoes::EditLine):Shoes::EditLine. Why is this? The method works in irb.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to split on the EditLine object, not its text.  You can get its text using the `text` method, like this:

```
    def convert_to_num(value)
    # Splits string into numerical values
        value.text.split(',').map { |num| num.to_i }
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you expect `value` to be a string. The `value` you pass to `to_rgb` is a `Shoes::EditLine`, and not a string. I know that from seeing the error message, not from reading the code. Your `convert_to_num` method is just fine, you just aren't passing the type of object you think you are to it.

I haven't programmed with Shoes before, so I'm not sure how to solve the problem, but now you know what's causing it at least.